# occasional crashes

Tags: crash

For the last few months, Ubuntu (20.04, on a thinkpad T480) has been crashing for me about once a week. When it happens, everything begins to get slow (everything starts to become unresponsive/laggy, until the mouse starts to slow down and then the screen is completely just frozen). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> doesn't do anything, I seemingly have no choice but to hard-reboot the computer. I'm usually using firefox at the time, but I'm not sure that means anything because I'm in general using firefox most of the time.

I thought it's about time i try to figure out what's going on and if there's anything I can do about it. On another question I saw that it might help to view the output of `journalctl -b -1 -e` after a crash, I did that and uploaded the output to https://pastebin.com/yZQpK5KT (below is an excerpt that meets the stackexchange character limit)

```
May 14 13:30:04 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400525.
May 14 13:30:06 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540052c.
May 14 13:30:57 Halley gnome-shell[32836]: ###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
May 14 13:32:36 Halley systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
May 14 13:32:36 Halley anacron[78434]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-05-14
May 14 13:32:36 Halley anacron[78434]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
May 14 13:32:36 Halley systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
May 14 13:35:27 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400533.
May 14 13:36:19 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540053a.
May 14 13:36:30 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400541.
May 14 13:37:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400548.
May 14 13:37:16 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540054f.
May 14 13:37:18 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400556.
May 14 13:37:25 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540055d.
May 14 13:37:38 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400564.
May 14 13:37:50 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540056b.
May 14 13:37:52 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400572.
May 14 13:37:54 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400579.
May 14 13:38:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400580.
May 14 13:39:48 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400587.
May 14 13:40:58 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540058e.
May 14 13:43:04 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400595.
May 14 13:43:32 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540059c.
May 14 13:43:40 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005a3.
May 14 13:44:45 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005aa.
May 14 13:45:12 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005b1.
May 14 13:49:16 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005b8.
May 14 13:50:12 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005bf.
May 14 13:50:16 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005c6.
May 14 13:51:01 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005cd.
May 14 13:51:17 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005d4.
May 14 13:51:29 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005db.
May 14 13:51:49 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005e2.
May 14 13:52:09 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005e9.
May 14 13:54:44 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005f0.
May 14 13:55:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005f7.
May 14 13:55:55 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x54005fe.
May 14 13:56:05 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400605.
May 14 13:56:08 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540060c.
May 14 13:58:13 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400613.
May 14 13:58:21 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540061a.
May 14 14:00:16 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400621.
May 14 14:00:52 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400628.
May 14 14:01:07 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x540062f.
May 14 14:03:58 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5400014 specified for 0x5400636.
May 14 14:04:29 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-5ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:04:29 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-19ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:04:31 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-7ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:04:33 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-8ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:04:33 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-21ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:04:35 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-9ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
May 14 14:05:35 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
May 14 14:17:01 Halley CRON[79125]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 14 14:17:01 Halley CRON[79126]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 14 14:17:02 Halley CRON[79125]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 14 14:17:10 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-2ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:17:10 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-26ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:18:30 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-6ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:18:57 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-33 noise=9999 txrate=130000
May 14 14:19:04 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-35 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:19:15 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-34 noise=9999 txrate=130000
May 14 14:19:31 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-44 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:19:39 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-36 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:19:51 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-36 noise=9999 txrate=52000
May 14 14:19:59 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-1ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:20:03 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-36 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:20:33 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-36 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:20:40 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-34 noise=9999 txrate=65000
May 14 14:20:45 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-36 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:21:09 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-33 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:21:15 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-36 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:23:01 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-12ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:23:01 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-25ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:30:01 Halley CRON[79289]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 14 14:30:01 Halley CRON[79290]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
May 14 14:30:01 Halley CRON[79289]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 14 14:35:10 Halley systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
May 14 14:35:10 Halley anacron[79347]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-05-14
May 14 14:35:10 Halley anacron[79347]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
May 14 14:35:10 Halley systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
May 14 14:37:21 Halley wpa_supplicant[855]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-36 noise=9999 txrate=144400
May 14 14:37:45 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-12ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:37:45 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-25ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:38:33 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-1ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:38:38 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-14ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:38:38 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-27ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:39:33 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-2ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:41:59 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-11ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:41:59 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-24ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
May 14 14:43:10 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
May 14 14:43:41 Halley gnome-shell[1807]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
May 14 14:53:34 Halley audit[79621]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/ICEauthority" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 14 14:53:34 Halley kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1621029214.593:143): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/ICEauthority" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 14 14:53:34 Halley kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1621029214.593:144): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/ICEauthority" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 14 14:53:34 Halley kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1621029214.593:145): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/ICEauthority" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 14 14:53:34 Halley kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1621029214.593:146): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/ICEauthority" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 14 14:53:34 Halley audit[79621]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/ICEauthority" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 14 14:53:34 Halley audit[79621]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/ICEauthority" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 14 14:53:34 Halley audit[79621]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/ICEauthority" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 14 14:53:36 Halley audit[79621]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/share/zoneinfo-icu/44/le/zoneinfo64.res" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 14 14:53:36 Halley kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1621029216.005:147): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/share/zoneinfo-icu/44/le/zoneinfo64.res" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 14 14:53:36 Halley kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1621029216.021:148): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/share/zoneinfo-icu/44/le/timezoneTypes.res" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 14 14:53:36 Halley audit[79621]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/share/zoneinfo-icu/44/le/timezoneTypes.res" pid=79621 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May 14 14:57:14 Halley nautilus[18122]: gtk_widget_get_mapped: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
May 14 14:57:14 Halley nautilus[18122]: gdk_window_is_visible: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
May 14 14:57:14 Halley nautilus[18122]: gdk_window_show_internal: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
May 14 14:57:14 Halley nautilus[18122]: gtk_widget_set_opacity: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
May 14 14:57:14 Halley nautilus[18122]: gtk_widget_queue_draw: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
May 14 14:57:16 Halley nautilus[18122]: gtk_widget_get_mapped: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
May 14 14:57:16 Halley nautilus[18122]: gdk_window_is_visible: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
May 14 14:57:16 Halley nautilus[18122]: gtk_widget_set_opacity: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
May 14 14:57:16 Halley nautilus[18122]: gtk_widget_queue_draw: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
May 14 14:58:37 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-14ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:58:37 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-35ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:58:38 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-12ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:58:38 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-25ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:59:03 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-11ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:59:14 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-6ms), your system is too slow
May 14 14:59:14 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-20ms), your system is too slow
May 14 15:00:53 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-8ms), your system is too slow
May 14 15:00:53 Halley /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1661]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-5ms), your system is too slow
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to interpret the information there, is it obvious to anyone what the issue is (and if not, what I should do differently to find out?)

Edit: as requested by heynnema, here is some more data (this was obtained some time after the last crash):

```
matt@Halley:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.5Gi       4.4Gi       651Mi       1.0Gi       2.5Gi       1.9Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi        11Mi       2.0Gi
matt@Halley:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
matt@Halley:~$ sudo swapon -s
[sudo] password for matt: 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 11912   -2
matt@Halley:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-memory                  
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: RMSA3260ME78HAF-2666
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 0
          serial: 13AE98AD
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 8
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 9
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: b
       version: N24ET56W (1.31 )
       date: 02/19/2020
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e824c000-e824ffff
matt@Halley:~$ top

top - 23:05:19 up  8:03,  1 user,  load average: 2.11, 1.67, 1.44
Tasks: 280 total,   1 running, 279 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.2 us,  1.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7724.2 total,    624.1 free,   4521.5 used,   2578.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2036.4 free,     11.6 used.   1937.7 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
   8992 matt      20   0   11984   4052   3404 R  12.5   0.1   0:00.02 top      
   2362 matt      20   0 5522484 967284 442828 S   6.2  12.2  85:46.18 firefox  
   2824 matt      20   0 4433992 645336 301120 S   6.2   8.2  15:49.62 Web Con+ 
   4189 matt      20   0 2686508 267744 139680 S   6.2   3.4   2:22.87 Web Con+ 
   4296 matt      20   0  481496  54644  39800 S   6.2   0.7   0:14.45 gnome-t+ 
      1 root      20   0  167508  10980   7844 S   0.0   0.1   1:08.18 systemd  
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd 
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp   
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par+ 
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+ 
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_perc+ 
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:01.20 ksoftir+ 
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:17.09 rcu_sch+ 
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.43 migrati+ 
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_in+ 
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0  
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1
```

and some more:

```
matt@Halley:~/Dropbox/introduction to combinatorics/homework 2021$ ls -al /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 May 11 01:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Oct 17  2019 ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SWAP**

**Note**: Your usage suggests that you might need to add more RAM.

Your 2G /swapfile is too small, let's increase it to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: His swap is hardly used at all: 11 MB out of 2 GB . I doubt if this is swap related. The problem MIGHT be that RAM is so low that the machine needs to swap at all; as desperation swapping sets in, everything comes to a screeching halt. Adding even more swap will only make the problem worse. What that machine really needs is more RAM, not more swap; or restarting that RAM-hungry browser every once in a while.

Comment: P.S. in all my 23 years of using Linux I **never** gave a machine more than 2 GB swap. If 2 GB are not enough, you are screwed anyway: If the system really starts using that much swap, it will be busy with just swapping all the time, leaving no CPU cycles for the user.

Comment: @HuHa We don't know the current uptime when the `free -h` command was given, so we don't know total swap usage, but you can see that RAM isn't the issue, in that case example of 1. OPs symptoms say a swap problem. You and I have also gone through the *"in all my 23 years of using Linux I never gave a machine more than 2 GB swap"* conversation before... and 2G /swapfile is almost NEVER enough.

Comment: It was always enough for whatever I did with my machines. Thus the "23 years".

Comment: @HuHa But with how much RAM?

Comment: That changed over the years, of course. But so did memory requirements (software keeps getting fatter all the time, just like we do). Most of my machines today have 8 GB which is plenty; only the machine I am writing this on has 16 GB, and even with a memory hungry game like War Thunder running in parallel and an Opera browser and an openSUSE Tumbleweed in a VirtualBox VM I rarely get beyond 6 GB used, leaving half the RAM for file buffers; and swap completely unused.

Comment: @HuHa That's good for you. However, many OPs use Chrome/Firefox with... I kid you not... 50 open tabs... and you know how that consumes memory! And they wonder why they have problems. Xubuntu/Lubuntu comes with a default 2G /swapfile, and it's almost never enough, out of the box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124290/discussion-between-huha-and-heynnema).

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! Did the two of you come to a conclusion about whether this change is a good idea? I'm a bit nervous about doing this, as it sounds like it might be a little dangerous...

Comment: Is there some way to get some kind of notification when I'm close to running out of memory, so that I can see whether that seems to be the cause of the crashes?

Comment: @Matt No problem. The change is minor, and safe, as long as you follow the instructions. And it should solve your problem. Report back.

Comment: @Matt You're not having crashes, you're having freezes. The `free -h` command is the quickest way to keep an eye on things.

Comment: @heynnema you were exactly right! I've been religiously monitoring my swap and it froze at basically the exact moment it ran out. I'll enlarge it as you suggested, but what I really want is for things to automatically close themselves to prevent the freeze as swap is close to running out, it's weird that that's not the default behaviour!

Comment: @Matt There is a process called OOM (out of memory) that supposed to kill processes like that, before the system freezes, but by the time it figures it out, it's usually too late. We either bump the swap, or add more RAM, or both... problem solved. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: an update on this: with increased swap, it crashes much less frequently, but after a long time using the system without rebooting it still slowly fills up the swap and crashes (strangely, the swap doesn't fully clear itself when i close and reopen my memory-hungry applications, I really have to reboot). Anyway I've installed "earlyoom" which is supposed to automatically kill things before the memory fills up, I expect that will solve my problem.

Comment: @Matt You may need to increase /swapfile from 4G to 8G, or add more RAM. Just double the count= value in my procedure. Use `free -h` to monitor swap usage. swap never clears itself or goes back to zero, so don't use that as a measurement criteria.

Comment: if I double it, doesn't that just mean I'll be able to go twice as long without a crash (but it will still crash)? my memory usage just seems to increase without limit over time, during the course of normal activity (mostly firefox).

Comment: @Matt It all depends on your usage pattern, and which apps you use, and how you use them. If you use Firefox with 40 open tabs, then you're just asking for trouble. It sounds like you need more RAM. However, increasing swap to 8G causes no harm, may solve your problem, or it may just delay any crashes longer. Go for it. Report back.